# How to get average from array

Tags: c++

Trying to get some C++ basics but have a problem. I need to get an average value of temperature array values. Posting code in here. I know that I've done something wrong, because I'm getting the wrong answers. Can you please tell me what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int d = 0, i;
    double avg = 0, sum = 0, Temperature[100];
    // -----------------------------------------
    cin >> d;
    for (i = 1; i <= d; i++)        
    {
        cin >> Temperature[i];
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= d; i++)
    {
        cout << Temperature[i] << endl;  // was Temperatura[i] ?
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= d; i++);
    {
        sum += Temperature[i];
    }
    avg= sum / d;
    cout << "Average: " << avg << " Sum: " << sum << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Array indices start at 0.

Comment: This time i am starting from 1 because user will get output about i value. day i temperature a[i]. So for him to understand better i would say day 1, not day 0.

Comment: Then output `i + 1`.

Comment: You are storing your result in a variable named `average` but printing out the result using a variable named `avg` which is never assigned anything. What I don't know is why you're not getting a compiler error since `average` doesn't seem to be declared anywhere. I'm guessing that this isn't really the code you're compiling and running - use copy/paste please.

Comment: avarega was my mistake :) had to rewrite code in english, did not saw this one

Comment: @chris: yes, array indices start at 0, but as long as he is consistent at using 1..d and d <= 99, the code is safe and self-consistent.  So that is not, of itself, the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a result of silly mistake:-

```
for (i = 1; i <= d; i++);  << semicolon
```

Remove semicolon from end of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it because the input number d is larger than 100

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int d = 0, i;
    double avg = 0, sum = 0, *Temperature=0;
    // -----------------------------------------
    cin >> d;
    Temperature=new  double[d];  //<== Use new to allocate array

    for (i = 0; i < d; i++)     //<== Normaly array start at 0       
    {
        cin >> Temperature[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        cout << Temperatura[i] <<endl;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++);
    {
        sum += Temperature[i];
    }
    average = sum / d;
    cout << "Average: " << avg << " Sum: " << sum << endl;
    if(Temperature!=0)              //<== Free  memory
    {
      delete []Temperature;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this doesnt. The output for sum i am getting for example: -2.53 45e-098  while i use values 3 2 and 6so there is a problem with value counting. This is the main problem.

Comment: Note (a) you have a `<= d` left in the code, and (b) you have a `Temperatura[i]` in the code too.  It's safe to delete a null pointer; if the memory allocation failed, you got an exception anyway, so the program will have aborted.  The test on `if (Temperature != 0)` is therefore redundant.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to initialize `int d;` if you are taking `d` as input before it use for first time.
- Once `d` taken as input. Now declare the `int Temperature[d];` so that if the total number of observation exceed 100 it should work.
- Now iterate the array, for taking input and calculating sum. **Note that** - Array indices starts from zero instead of one. Goes to `d-1`.
- `for()` loop doesn't have`;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. You declare the Temperatures array, the number of temperatures (you used 'd', but you don't need to initialize it with 0, just read it) and a variable which keeps the sum of Temperatures (ex.: double sum = 0)
2. In a for loop (for i = 1; i <= d; i++  ||  for i = 0; i < d; i++) you read the Temperatures and increase the sum with each of the elemens (sum += Temperatures[i] || sum = sum + Temperatures[i]
3. Output: cout  << sum / n;  Formula : average = (elem1 + elem2 + ... + elem n) / n